# Controller not working after publish to azure website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have created a simple web site using ASP.Net MVC 4, Internet Application.  I added a controller, model and associated views for a new page.  Everything works fine running locally, I can register, login and use my new page functionality.  After publishing to Azure website I can successfully use the home, about, register, login all of the built in functionality.  However I cannot navigate to my new content I added, it gives an error 500.  Again all of this functionality does work locally.  I am very new to ASP.Net MVC and could use any help I can get.

RouteConfig

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Index action of my added controller

```
private UsersContext uc = new UsersContext();
    private UserProfile user = new UserProfile();
    private Character character = new Character();
    //
    // GET: /Character/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        user = uc.UserProfiles.Single(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
        return View(uc.Characters.ToList().Where(c => c.AccountOwnerId == user.UserId));
    }
```

Let me know if any other items would help.  Oh I put this into my UsersContext instead of in a newly created DbContext.

```
public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Character> Characters { get; set; }
```

EDIT: one thing i forgot to mention is that when i published, it did not add the email address field to userprofile or my entire Character table.  I had to run SQL on the Azure manage portal to manually add those items.

Comment: Did you publish using the publish settings downloaded from your Azure portal?

Comment: Yes i did publish from VS using the downloaded .PublishSettings file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the frustration of trying to understand why this wasn't working I decided to start over.  I deleted the website from Azure as well as the SQL DB.  I then added a new website and SQL DB then grabbed the new publish settings file.  I imported that into VS and Published.  It all worked with a fresh install, not sure what I botched the first time around but it is working as intended now.  Thanks,